# get_results query with accent

Tags: wpdb

I'm trying to do an SQL query and I don't understand something. I get a value with `$ _POST`, this value is equal to 'définition'. I made this request:
`$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM". $ wpdb-> prefix. "posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%". $ _POST ['value']. "% '";`.

A `var_dump($sql)` gives `"SELECT DISTINCT * FROM datatablename.posts WHERE post_title LIKE '% definition%'";`.

If I do `$res = $wpdb->get_results($sql);`, I get an empty array

But, if in my code I put directly `$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM datatablename.posts WHERE post_title LIKE '% definition%'";` (I immediately replace `$_POST` with my value), `$res` is an array with a post.

The problem stems from the accent, because if `$_POST['value'] = 'finition'` it's okay

My data table is in `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.

What can be done to solve this problem?

Comment: As an aside you probably ought to [$wpdb->esc_like()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/esc_like/) and [esc_sql()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_sql/) your `$_POST['value']` when assembling the search string.

Comment: But if you can't get MySQL to match definition with and without the accent then you possibly need some other search mechanism set up. Either add extra stripped-diacritics versions of titles and content to search, or use some external search mechanism that will handle this automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL command is highly **insecure** and open to security issues like SQL injection, so even if this may not answer the question, I strongly suggest you to use [`$wpdb->prepare()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) and [`$wpdb->esc_like()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/esc_like/) — the latter is used to escape the `%` character in SQL.

Additionally, you can simply use `$wpdb->posts` to output the table name for WordPress posts such as `wp_posts`.

And I noticed that in your SQL command:

- The table name is incorrect because the `FROM` and `$wpdb->prefix` is concatenated as one word like `FROMwp_posts`.
- There's a whitespace after the second `%` in the `LIKE` clause: `%". $_POST['value']. "% '` — so that whitespace is probably not needed? Or that it could be the reason why the query did not return any results.
- The `var_dump()` actually contains no accent — you used `definition` and not `définition`. Same goes with the direct one.

Now here's how your query or SQL command should be generated:

```php
$value = $_POST['value'] ?? '';

// wrapped for brevity
$sql = $wpdb->prepare( "
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM {$wpdb->posts}
WHERE post_title LIKE %s
", '%' . $wpdb->esc_like( $value ) . '%' );

$res = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
```

And I actually tested the above code with a post with the title containing the word `définition`, and the query returned one result (which is a test post).

If my code doesn't work for you, you can try [`sanitize_text_field()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/), but that will strip HTML tags, among other things.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function to query posts with title "like" - returning either IDs or specified columns - escaping both the passed title and any requested column values:

```
/**
* Get post with title %like% search term
*
* @param       $title          Post title to search for
* @param       $method         wpdb method to use to retrieve results
* @param       $columns        Array of column rows to retrieve
*
* @since       0.3
* @return      Mixed           Array || False
*/
function posts_with_title_like( $title = null, $method = 'get_col', $columns = array ( 'ID' ) ){

    // sanity check ##
    if ( ! $title ) { return false; }

    // global $wpdb ##
    global $wpdb;

    // First escape the $columns, since we don't use it with $wpdb->prepare() ##
    $columns = \esc_sql( $columns );

    // now implode the values, if it's an array ##
    if( is_array( $columns ) ){
        $columns = implode( ', ', $columns ); // e.g. "ID, post_title" ##
    }

    // run query ##
    $results = $wpdb->$method (
            $wpdb->prepare (
            "
                SELECT $columns
                FROM $wpdb->posts
                WHERE {$wpdb->posts}.post_title LIKE %s
            "
            ,   \esc_sql( '%'.$wpdb->esc_like( trim( $title )  ).'%' )
            )
        );

    #var_dump( $results );

    // return results or false ##
    return $results ? $results : false ;

}
```